# How to monitor JBOSS 7.1.1.Final with check_jmx in linux

Tags: jboss7.x, nagios

I am able to connect to the `JMX Beans` with `Jconsole` with the followed `URL`:

```
service:jmx:remoting-jmx://127.0.0.1:9999
```

When it gives same kind of `URL` with `check_jmx` as follows I am unable to connect to the `JMX Beans`

```
./check_jmx -U service:jmx:remoting-jmx://127.0.0.1:9999 -O java.lang:type=Threading -A ThreadCount
JMX CRITICAL Unsupported protocol: remoting-jmx
```

How to use the `jmx` `URL` to connect with `check_jmx` to the `jboss 7.1.1` version ?

Answer (score 1):

JBoss 7 doesn't support checking through JMX anymore. The alternative for you could be use:

- [Jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org/index.html)
- [check_jmx4perl](http://search.cpan.org/~roland/jmx4perl/scripts/check_jmx4perl#SYNOPSIS)

Another alternative would be to use SNMP:

- [JVM monitoring via SNMP of JBoss EAP 6 worker nodes with pnp4nagios
  Template](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JVMMonitoringViaSNMPOfJBossEAP6WorkerNodesWithPnp4nagiosTemplate)